# How to hijack a form using a jQuery dialog and then continue with the submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="cancel" method="post" action="/Controller/Cancel">
   <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Go">
   ...
```

I'm using jQuery with a jQuery UI dialog.  What I'd like to do is hijack the submit of the form and display a dialog.  When the user clicks 'yes' in the dialog, the form carries on and does a normal page submit.  If they click 'No', the dialog just cancels.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            // Not sure what to do here
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#cancel').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});

});
```

My question is, how do I get the submit code to return true/false to the client based on the response from the dialog.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I won't post that as an answer, but do know you can do it without the use of jQuery with JavaScript `confirm()` function, it returns whether `true` or `false` depending on the user's input in the GUI, so you could just do `areYouSure = confirm("Are you sure?"); return areYouSure;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use  `$('#cancel').submit()` within the "Yes" button callback, the `submit` event is triggered again and `event.preventDefault()` stops the from from actually being submitted.

A quick fix would be to unbind your submit event just before actually submitting the form. (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WQjFj/6/)

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $('#cancel').unbind("submit").submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Another solution can be found on this answer: [Using jquery ui dialog to confirm action for form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420773/using-jquery-ui-dialog-to-confirm-action-for-form-submission/2420806#2420806)

Comment: Thanks.  The demo on jsfiddle was very helpful.  Not seen that site before - will use it again!

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the form directly from the dialog. Where you have //Not sure what to do here, put

```
$("#cancel").submit();
```

Here's a guide you may have seen:

http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/