# Jquery, catch event submit and do something before the real submit

Tags: jquery, events, submit

Here you can see my code :

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure ?", function(response) {
        if(response){
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

So, i catch the submit event and i want the user confirm before really submit.

In my example i have a problem, if a user confirm OK, response is true, so i do `$('form').submit();`. After that, my code catch once again the submit event, and the confirm dialog still appears once. It is an infinite loop.

How can i fix that ? Thanks !

Comment: bind a click event to the submit button instead

Comment: i need to catch any way to submit the form, on enter, on touch specific button on mobile... it's why i use .submit()

Comment: pressing enter, or tapping on a touchscreen counts as clicking submit

Comment: Oh, yes...not very logical. But thanks :p

Comment: are you submitting by refreshing the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confirm form submission using bootbox.confirm()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313586/confirm-form-submission-using-bootbox-confirm)