# Bootstrap Modal - How to Return True if Yes Button is Clicked - Customized Confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Okay, I've spent whole day reading Q&A but still couldn't get it done. I needed to create a customized confirm() wherein instead of the default dialog, I use bootstrap modal to return true if user clicks Yes, return false for No.

Example:

`<a href="remove.php?id=3" onclick="return custom_confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this?');" />`

and my custom confirm function is:

```
function custom_confirm(message) {
  //  put message into the body of modal
  $('#modal-custom-confirmation').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  //  store current modal reference
    var modal = $(this);

    //  update modal body help text
    modal.find('.modal-body #modal-help-text').text(message);
  });

  //  show modal ringer custom confirmation
  $('#modal-custom-confirmation').modal('show');

  //  if Yes button is clicked, return true
  //  if No  button is clicked,  return false
  //  logic here...
}
```

My modal is here:

```
<!--  modal: custom confirmation  -->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="modal-custom-confirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-help-title">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong class="modal-title" id="modal-help-title">Confirm</strong>
      </div><!--  /.modal-header  -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="modal-help-text"></p>
      </div><!--  /.modal-body  -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div><!--  /.modal-footer  -->
    </div><!--  /.modal-content  -->
  </div><!--  /.modal-dialog  -->
</div><!--  /.modal  -->
```

Comment: The same thing happened to me in the past, and finally I had to use a library outside http://bootboxjs.com/.

Comment: @TranAudi, thank you! You nailed it here: http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#also-applies-to-alert-prompt-customwith-alternate-button-tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and comment everyone. I've finally solved it. As suggested, I used a library called [Bootbox.js and use a customized confirm with alternate button text](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#also-applies-to-alert-prompt-customwith-alternate-button-tex) (no need to reinvent the wheel, just tweak it to suit the need)

Then I incorporated the answers of: [Nuno Reis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18912991/2589643), [Fabien Ménager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2589643), and [Ryan McGeary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2589643), to create the solution. Here's what I did:

1. **Add class as identifier** for links to use this custom confirmation. In my code, I used `custom-confirm-link`.
2. **Put confirmation message** into data bind `data-confirmation`.

   So my link now looks like this:

   ```
   <a href="remove.php?id=3" class="custom-confirm-link" data-confirmation="Are you sure you want to remove this?" />
   ```
3. **In footer, I added click event listener to links** with class `custom-confirm-link`. Inside:

   - I **retrieved the link** triggered, its `href` and its confirmation message through data bind `data-confirmation`
   - I did `preventDefault()` to the event
   - popped **a bootbox.js confirm with custom label** for `confirm` (yes) and `cancel` (no),
   - and **utilized its callback to process the result**
   - Only when **confirm button yes is clicked will I simulate the clicking of link** through `window.location.href`.

That's it. Here's the click event listener code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //  click event listener to links that requires custom confirm
    $('.custom-confirm-link').click(function(e){

        //  get link and its confirmation message
        var link                = $(this);
        var confirmationmessage = link.data('confirmation');
        var address             = link.attr('href');

        e.preventDefault();

        bootbox.confirm({
            title   : 'Confirm',
            message : confirmationmessage,
            buttons : {
                confirm : {
                    label : 'Yes',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel : {
                    label : 'No',
                    className : 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
            callback : function (result) {
                if (result)
                {
                    //  simulate click the link
                    window.location.href = address;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Click event is inherently non blocking and async. Unlike native `confirm`. So you can't return `true` or `false`. You have to somehow handle the async nature of user interaction.

The most straight forward way would be to pass a callback

```
function custom_confirm(message, callback) {
  //  put message into the body of modal
  $('#modal-custom-confirmation').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  //  store current modal reference
    var modal = $(this);

    //  update modal body help text
    modal.find('.modal-body #modal-help-text').text(message);
  });

  //  show modal ringer custom confirmation
  $('#modal-custom-confirmation').modal('show');

  $('#modal-custom-confirmation button.ok').off().on('click', function() {
     // close window
     $('#modal-custom-confirmation').modal('hide');

     // and callback
     callback(true);
  });

  $('#modal-custom-confirmation button.cancel').off().on('click', function() {
     // close window
     $('#modal-custom-confirmation').modal('hide');
     // callback
     callback(false);
  });
}
```

And in HTML

```
...
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ok">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel">No</button>
      </div>
...
```

If you want to actually return something you could return a Promise that would resolve to either `true` or `false`. But still async code remains async.

Comment: so basically, I cannot use my code to mimic a customized confirm() right?

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri Did you mean `confirm`? If yes then no. :) `confirm` blocks javascript execution.

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri If you check almost every library to make customized prompts and confirms they use either callbacks or promises (or both).

Comment: I see. I got it now. Thank you. Yup, you are right. I'll post an answer now.

Comment: this solution gives me error "callback is not a function" .. ??

Comment: ```function custom_confirm(message, callback)``` while calling to function , what to pass in callback param??